# Is there a way to get all beans with scope prototype that are injected via @Autowired?

Tags: java, spring, autowired, prototype-scope

Injecting bean with scope `prototype` with `@Autowired` usually doesn't work as expected. But when writing code, it's easy to accidentally inject a prototype.

Is there a way to get a list of all `@Autowired` fields and methods and to match that with a Spring AppContext to check for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to override `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`(which is responsible for processing @Autowired, @Inject, @Resource etc) and perform the checks that you have mentioned in this overridden bean post processor. However, AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor gets registered with quite a few of the common custom namespaces (`context:component-scan`, `context:annotation-config` etc), so these custom annotations will have to be replaced with the corresponding `bean` variation and the overridden post processor also registered as a bean.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan :-) Looking at the source, I'll have to copy half of the code because it doesn't give me a good place to hook into the bean lookup :-(